# How to force a class to implement a property that derives from a specific base class/interface (rather than is of a specific type)

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class, base-class

In my solution, there are a number of classes `C1`, `C2`, `C3` etc. that all inherit from a common abstract base class `CB`.

There are also a number of classes `D1`, `D2`, `D3` etc. that act as a data-source for the corresponding `C` class (e.g. the data-source for `C1` is a local property of type `D1` etc). The `D` classes all inherit from a common abstract base class `DB`, but vary in their implementation (both inherited and non-inherited properties & methods are used by the `C` class).

Now, I want to impose a rule that all `C` classes (i.e. that derive from `CB`) **must** implement a "data-source" property, and the type of this property **must** be derived from `DB`.

My initial idea was to do this:

```
public abstract class CB
{
    protected abstract DB DataSource { get; set; } 

    etc.
}
```

However, this means that the overridden `DataSource` property in the `C` classes can only be of type `DB`, not a type derived from `DB`.

How can I impose my rule? Ideally `CB` and `DB` would remain abstract base classes (because there are non-abstract properties and methods in each that I wish the `C` and `D` classes to inherit), but they could be converted to interfaces if needed. However I think I have exactly the same problem if I do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for generic class:

```
public abstract class CB<T> where T : DB
{
    protected abstract T DataSource { get; set; } 

    etc
}
```

Now, `C1` should be defined as:

```
public class C1 : CB<D1>
{
    protected override D1 DataSource { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I understand the first code snippet, but for the 2nd don't you mean: C1 should be defined as: 
public class C1 : CB<D1> { protected override D1 DataSource { get; set; } }